# Passing values to another function in Python?

Tags: python, function

I currently have 4 functions, of which I need to connect. I have the first function, which formats a csv file and turns out 4 values, the numbers of (useful) rows and columns and two different lists. Then, the next two functions have to use the values from the first function to calculate some things. Finally, the main function (the last one) will take those calculated values and produce an output. I'm really struggling in learning how to pass the output's of the functions to the other ones. Currently it looks (really roughly) like this:

```
def formatting():
    ...
    n = 30
    m = 9
    array = [...]
    tot = [...]
    return(n, m, array, tot)

def calculation():
    formatting()
    # a bunch of code that uses n, m, array and tot
    mn = [...]
    mx = [...]
    av = [...]
    sd = [...]
    return(mn, mx, av, sd)

def cor():
   formatting()
   # a bunch of code that uses n, m, array and tot
   rs = [...]
   return(rs)

def main(csvfile):
   calculation()
   cor()
main()
```

It keeps telling me that there is an error in the first function, saying that m is not defined (first line in which a passed variable is used), meaning that the value from m has not passed to the calculation function and hence won't be usable in any of the other functions. Can someone explain to me how I can pass this correctly?

I also need to have an argument in the main function, which lists the file to be analyzed and I need to pass that onto formatting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return values of `formatting` to variables before you can use them in the other function, e.g.

```
def calculation():
    m, n, array, tot = formatting()
    # a bunch of code that uses n, m, array and tot
    mn = [...]
    mx = [...]
    av = [...]
    sd = [...]
    return(mn, mx, av, sd)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is why I hate coding sometimes, been searching for 5 hours over hundreds of sites and lecture notes, trying to understand what passing by reference actually meant and then I have it explained as simply as this.

Comment: Oh I have one more question if you have time. I forgot to add that my main function needs to have an argument, like def main(csvfile):

Which I then need to pass onto my formatting function, to do it's job. How can I do that?

Comment: You would need to pass it as an input variable to `formatting` as well (and `calculation` and `cor` since these are calling `formatting` as well). You will need to change the signature of the functions for this, e.g. `def main(csvfile):...`, `def formatting(csvfile):...`, etc.

Comment: How do I pass it as an input variable? Just something like csvfile1 = csvfile and then use csvfile1 in my code for formatting?

Comment: No, you van use the input parameter directly in the definition of `formatting` e.g. `def formatting(csvfile): print(csvfile)`. In `main` you could call `formatting` according to `def main(csvfile): formatting(csvfile)`. This would pass the value of `csvfile` as an input argument to `formatting`.

Comment: I'm actually unable to use the print or input function (for testing purposes) in this script. Is that the onlly way I can pass the argument in main into formatting? If so, I guess I need to restructure all my functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
def formatting():
    ...
    n = 30
    m = 9
    array = [...]
    tot = [...]
    return(n, m, array, tot)

def calculation():
    n,m,array,tot = formatting()
    # a bunch of code that uses n, m, array and tot
    mn = [...]
    mx = [...]
    av = [...]
    sd = [...]
    return(mn, mx, av, sd)

def cor():
   n,m,array,tot = formatting()
   # a bunch of code that uses n, m, array and tot
   rs = [...]
   return(rs)

def main():
   calculation()
   cor()
main()
```

When you want to use values from different functions, you should assign them to variable while calling and then use those assigned variables to do calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is Python packing and unpacking feature.

[Check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) for details on Packing and Unpacking